# How to reverse iterate vector with iterator?

Tags: c++

for example:

```
for(int i=0;i<v.size();i++){

}
```

is normal order,

```
for(int i=v.size()-1;i>=0;i--){

}
```

is reversed order,

how about reverse version of iterator?

```
for(vector<int>::iterator it=v.begin();it!=v.end();++it){

}
```

also is there any reverse version of this code style?

```
for(int i : v){

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use a [reverse iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator):

```
for(auto it = v.rbegin(); it != v.rend(); ++it){/*...*/}
```

There is no built in way to do a range based `for` in reverse, but you could use [`boost::adaptors::reversed`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/reversed.html):

```
for(auto& i : boost::adaptors::reversde(v)){/*...*/}
```

Comment: The adaptor is named reverse**d**. Are you sure it can be used that way? I would've guessed `for(auto& i : (v | boost::adaptors::reversed)){/*...*/}`